# InverseLaplaceTransform gives inconsistent results

Tags: bugs, integral-transforms

These should give the same results, but they do not:

```
InverseLaplaceTransform[1/Sqrt[x] HeavisideTheta[x + 1], x, y]

InverseLaplaceTransform[1/Sqrt[x], x, y]
```

Results:

```
Erf[Sqrt[y]]/(Sqrt[Pi] Sqrt[y])

1/(Sqrt[Pi] Sqrt[y])
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: I think this is a bug. BTW, it is unclear how `InverseLaplaceTransform[1/Sqrt[x] HeavisideTheta[x + 1], x, y]` is found. According to the documentation, this is a certain improper integral in the complex plane, but  `HeavisideTheta[]` makes no sense there.

Comment: fyi, Maple can't evaluate it. `inttrans:-invlaplace(1/sqrt(x)*Heaviside(x+1),x,y)` returns unevaluated.

Comment: @Nasser: It is natural since FT and inverse FT of distributions are hard matter (`HeavisideTheta` is a distribution ( more exactly, the implementation of the certain distribution in Mathematica)). –